# Pass context from TestSuite to JUnit test classes

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I have the following requirement:

- Create a TestSuite class which initialize some variables which are required by all test classes.
- Pass this variable to all classes.

so, I created the following TestSuite class:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ //
    LoginCommandTest.class //   
})
public class GameTestSuite {
  private static Vertx vertx;

  @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws IOException
      vertx = ....
       ...
    }
}
```

and the test-class

```
public class LoginCommandTest {

  @Test
  public void testLogin() {
    vertx.someMethod();
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I pass `vertx` initialized in `@BeforeClass` of `GameTestSuite` into `LoginCommandTest` ??

Answer (score 1):

If you use JUnit 5, have a look at this project, that integrates vert-x with Jupiter: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-junit5 It implements an extension that cares about creating and providing (a shared) vert-x context to each test container or method.

If it doesn't fit your needs, roll your own specialized extension. Details at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at that.

Comment: It looks promising, can it all be wrapped in a TestSuite?

Comment: TestSuite is a JUnit 4 feature, JUnit 5 is not there, yet. See https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/744 and related issues.

Comment: Cool! I will follow this issue - hopefully it will be available soon ..it's a much required capability.

Comment: for some reason I can't find the library on maven-repo! any idea?

Comment: Try jitpack.io https://jitpack.io/#vert-x3/vertx-junit5/master-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly but you can make vertx public or protected and access it from LoginCommandTest like any other static variable `GameTestSuite.vertx`.

Comment: Yeah, it can work, but I’m hoping for something more structural.  Thanks 